# SMD jumper design rules

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, jumper

The SMD jumper. One of the most basic devices on any board using SMD technology.

Yet, considering devices from various sources and looking into the hints of designing it, I get differing techniques and points of view.

The properties under consideration:

1. Size of the pads. Some designers point to the device size being comparable to standard 0 Ohm resistor size to put in place - e.g. 0603, 0805. This gives good reference for the device design, but it leaves question open on what must be a gap between the pads.
2. Solder mask. This one is actually why I started to investigate the matters. People say you won't want having solder mask between the jumper pads. Yet I have these designs in standard EAGLE library:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first device, called SJ, is having tStop (mask stop) area in between the pads, others do not. These are from standard EAGLE library called `jumper.lbr`.

3. Number of pads. The simplest one at the very top has 2 pads, thus single jumping area. But what's about 3 pads jumper, with 2 jumping areas? Need to have mask in between? What its properties must be in order to have the most effective removal and insertion of solder jumpers?

Comment: How well do you solder/unsolder?  If you have a steady hand and use a small tip, then small pads close together are fine.  I would use the spacing recommended by your board source to have solder mask between pads to avoid hard to clean shorts between pads when a jumper is removed.  Usually something like 8 mil, as you would have between pins on a tightly spaced leaded device like a microprocessor.